# Editing line in csv with python

Tags: python, csv, editing

Here is my code so far:

```
def edit_assignment():
    print 'Select Assignment'
    list_assignment()
    f1 = open(fdir, 'r')
    lines = f1.readlines()
    f1.close()
    line_to_edit = raw_input('Assignment to edit(start from 0): ')
    if os.path.exists(fdir):
        f = open(fdir, "w")
        t1 = raw_input('TEST:')
        lines[int(line_to_edit)] 
        f.writelines()
        f.close()        
    else:
        check()
        edit_assignment()
```

This is part of a larger code, but I can't figure out how to get a get it to replace line X in a csv. I've been stuck on this for a while and not sure where to go.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: For now its supposed to just write 'x' instead of any user defined text, just to get it working. It is supposed to edit a certain line in the csv by emptying the file and re writing.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be improved upon but it does work. Simply change `output_array[row_to_edit]` to the row you'd like to edit and the corresponding value, then it will rewrite the CSV using that data.

```
import csv

c = csv.reader(open('YourCSV.csv', 'rU'))

output_array = []
for row in c:
    output_array.append(row)

output_array[row_to_edit] = 'Edited'

writer = csv.writer(open('YourCSV.csv', 'wb'))

for row in output_array:
    writer.writerow(row)
```